# In Powershell Retrieving Printed Message From SSMS

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Our DBA team doesn't verify the backups using the below `TSQL` (which can easily be done post-backup and takes almost no time, so I don't get why not):

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = 'D:\Backups\LOCATION'
```

They've had issues in the past, so even though we'd think they'd learn from it, they haven't.  I created a Powershell script to do this because we have about 100+ servers and I just want to run this script against all the backups just to ensure they're valid.  The below script runs correctly (in that it doesn't break or throw errors), I am curious if there's a way to get the printed message back in Powershell that we would normally get in SSMS where it states *The backup set on file 1 is valid* as verification.

```
$SqlCon = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlCon.ConnectionString = "SERVER=SERV\INST;Integrated Security=true;DATABASE=master"

$baks = Get-ChildItem "D:\Backups\" -Filter *.BAK

foreach ($bak in $baks)
{
    $SqlCon.Open()
    $cd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $cd.Connection = $SqlCon

    $cd.CommandText = "RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = @f"
    $cd.Parameters.Add("@f", $bak.FullName)
    $cd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $SqlCon.Close()
}
```

Comment: `invoke-sqlcmd -verbose` ?

Comment: `Invoke-SqlCmd ... -Verbose` is also nice if you want to [redirect the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1) for later use instead of just printing it to the host immediately.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Capturing InfoMessage Output (PRINT, RAISERROR) from SQL Server using PowerShell](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/capturing-infomessage-output-print-raiserror-from-sql-server-using-powershell/)

The trick, as Jonathan points out, is that you need to have a listener attached to the connection manager listening for the print or error actions.

```
$cd.Parameters.Add("@f", $bak.FullName) | Out-Null
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) Write-Host $event.Message }
$SqlCon.add_InfoMessage($handler)
$SqlCon.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true
```

I also piped the output of adding a parameter to `Out-Null` as that was noise I didn't need.